# Resolution of function arguments/parameters in C++

Tags: c++, templates, rvalue, perfect-forwarding

I am currently working my way through 'Effective Modern C++' to update my knowledge of the language, and have just finished item 27, which deals with overloading functions which take forwarding (or universal as the book calls them) references. Using the following code I wrote:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void func(T&& param) {
    std::cout << "forwarding reference version\n";
}

void func(int param) {
    std::cout << "int version\n";
}

int main() {
    func(29);
}
```

Please can someone explain why the int version is called, even though 29 is an rvalue and therefore the template should instantiate to "void func(int&& param)" and the call should be to the forwarding version? Obviously it is what it is so my understanding is clearly lacking, but clarification on this point would be helpful. I understand that the standard says in the case of identical function signatures, a non-templated function should be preferred, but (in my mind at least) this doesn't apply here? Many thanks.

Regards,
Phil

Comment: Note `func(int&&)` is not a better match than `func(int)`.  If you have those two as non-templates, the call is ambiguous.

Comment: Because surely the template match void func(int&& param) would be better than void func(int param) - they are not the same. Or am I just being an idiot? Entirely possible I admit :-)

Comment: @aschepler: ah, I see, that is where my lack of understanding is. I assumed they would be different and overloadable - haven't actually tried that. Please post that as an answer and I will happily accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call `func(29)` matches the function  `void func(int)` with no conversions required. This is known as *identity conversion* for overload resolution, which is in the ranking category *Exact Match*.

The ranking rules for *best viable function* in [over.match.best] specify when functions are a better match than other functions during overload resolution.

An identity conversion is never a worse conversion sequence than any other conversion sequence, according to [over.ics.rank], so `void func(int)` can never be beaten under the first 5 rules.  Rule 6 is:

> F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function
>   F2 if for all arguments
>
> [...]
>
> F1 is not a function template specialization and F2 is a function template specialization, [...]

So a non-template identity conversion always wins over any template instantiation.